# i tried to load a img in django website but it is not loaded

Tags: python, html, django, image, web

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1  >Blog Home!</h1>
{% load static %}
<img src ="{% static 'images/imgtest.jpg' %}" />
</body>
</html>
</!Doctype html>
```

[this is the code Tree and the code in HTML please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RbFd.png)

Comment: Can you share the relevant `settings.py` settings and `urls.py` (that includes the paths for static and media urls). Note that Django does not serve static/media files in production (with `DEBUG = False`).

Comment: A `!Doctype` by the way has *no* closing tag.

Comment: thanks every one i solve it and i will learn from my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you indent the `<img>` tag. It is part of the body, `!DOCTYPE` has no closing tag , and use `{% load static %}` Before `!DOCTYPE` for ease of use. Also, like **@Gaurav** said, make sure that your settings have a static url and a dir for the files.

Here is the HTML fixed:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1  >Blog Home!</h1>

    <img src ="{% static 'images/imgtest.jpg' %}" />
</body>
</html>
```

If you still have problems, refer to [This Website (docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: There is no reason to indent the `img` tag, except for ease of reading

Comment: Agreed, @MeL. I said this because it is pretty much an HTML convention.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your settings.py at the bottom.

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
```